# Why is ConnectedProps not inferring the correct type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a root redux state defined:

```
interface RootState {
    users: User[]
}
```

In my components I would like to use `ConnectedProps` to automatically create the props type from my state mapping and dispatch mapping:

```
const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
    users: state.users
});

const mapDispatch = {
    deleteUser: (id: number) => (deleteUser(id)) // deleteUser action creator defined in another file
}

const connector = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)

type Props = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
```

However when I try to map over users in my component with `props.users.map(user => {...` I get a type error:

`Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type`.

Why is it treating `users` as an `Any[]` rather than a `User[]`?

Note I do not get this error if I replace `Props` with

```
interface Props {
    users: User[]
}
```

Comment: perhaps you could try `state.users as RootState.users`

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding the type to my map function solved the issue:

`props.users.map((user: User) => {...`